# Create two columns of entry fields using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, user-input

I want to create a dynamic GUI that will change the number of input boxes based on a user input (numshoes)

I have successfully done that below... however, I want two input boxes per row, right now I only have one.

I thought `self.entrys[-1].grid(row=ii, column=2)` would add another column of inputs, but I still only have one.

Any thoughts?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

numshoes = 6 
shoes = ['shoe1', 'shoe2', 'shoe3', 'shoe4', 'shoe5','shoe6']

master = tk.Tk()

class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.variables = []
        for i in range(numshoes):
            self.variables.append(StringVar())

        self.labels = []
        self.entrys = []
        for ii in range(numshoes):
            char = str((shoes[ii]))
            self.labels.append(Label(root , text = char))
            self.labels[-1].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=ii, column=0)
            self.entrys.append(Entry(root, textvariable =self.variables[ii]))
            self.entrys[-1].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=ii, column=1)
            self.entrys[-1].grid(row=ii, column=2)

root = Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Finish',command=master.quit).grid(row=(numshoes+1), column=1,sticky =tk.W, pady=4)

# root.geometry("200x600+50+50")
T = test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code won't run. It's missing lots of pieces. However, looking at your code I see you're only creating one entry. First you put it in column 1 and then you put it in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought self.entrys[-1].grid(row=ii, column=2) would add another column of inputs, but I still only have one.

No, it only moves that entry to column 2. If you want two `Entry` widgets on a row you have to create two `Entry` widgets for each row.